# Azure app service breaks with node process managers but works with node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, pm2

I have a weird problem I've been scratching my head over. I have an express app which uses pm2 in production mode

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 start ./src/index.js
```

This works perfectly fine locally. However when I deploy this to Azure App service, the container keeps crashing. I can see the pm2 process starting successfully in the logs but the app then crashes with the following error message

> Container didn't respond to pings on port 8080

I have tried setting `WEBSITES_PORT` to `8080` and I've tried using `process.env.PORT` and hard coding the port to `8080` but nothing has worked.

Does anyone know what might be the cause? I prefer not having to run the application against node in production.

**Update** 
I just tried this with [supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor/) and had the same result. Looks like there is something about process managers that's a problem here, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you start your `node` server, you should specify the port as given from the environment.

*Basic* example:

```
const LOCAL_APP_PORT = 9300;

server.create({ port: process.env.port || LOCAL_APP_PORT })
```

*Note*: In order to debug if is `pm2` related or not, try for instance to start it simply with `node` command.

**Update**

Based on your last comment. I think the issue might be that `pm2` daemonizes itself by default. Could you try to pass the `--no-daemon` flag to `pm2` command?

Comment: Hey, thanks but I've already tried this as I mentioned in my question but it did not work.

Comment: Okay, that seems to work actually. Do you think it would be a problem not running it as a daemon?